# Can't insert data into my local mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Hi I'm having problems inserting into my local database, I have an established connection as I can query using "SELECT * FROM contact", but I cannot insert using the following code

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO 'contact' ('e-mail', 'subject', 'body')
VALUES('email@gmail.com', 'another question', 'Just asking?')";
```

This is the error it's giving me - 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''e-mail', 'subject', 'body')

If anyone could kindly assist?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. no need for ' around table name

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO contact (`e-mail`, `subject`, `body`)VALUES('email@gmail.com', 'another question', 'Just asking?')";
```

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO contact ('e-mail', 'subject', 'body') VALUES('email@gmail.com', 'another question', 'Just asking?')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''e-mail', 'subject', 'body')   ######Still receive this error

Comment: make sure colunm names e-mail are the same as your database

Comment: your `'` is `\``? (shift+~ key)


`$query1 = "INSERT INTO \`contact\` (\`e-mail\`, \`subject\`, \`body\`)VALUES('email@gmail.com', 'another question', 'Just asking?')";`

Comment: It was the fact that I didn't use backticks for columns, i was unaware of this, I'm following a course right now that has been really good however it appears that things have changed since, thank you to everyone!